# two plots per slide at same location with same size on many slides

Tags: macros, microsoft-powerpoint

I want to place two pictures per slide one left one of the right side. This pattern would be repeated over many slides with different figures representing same quantities for different scenarios. However, I'd like the figures on different slides to be of at the same location and have the same size. For instance, if we name figure on left as A1 and the one on the right as B1 where "1" is the slide number, then location/size of A1, A2, A3, ... are the same and location/size of B1,B2, B3, ... are the same. How can I achieve this without manual adjustment of location and dimensions?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like using a layout such as "Two Content" might meet your needs?

Right click on the slide on the left hand side panel of powerpoint, choose layout and then choose the "Two Content" layout option.

[image: Layout menu choice]

If it doesn't quite meet your sizing requirements, you can of course edit the Slide Master accordingly (from View -> Slide Master).